# Implementing Matsort and Matpaginator in Angular Material TreeTable Component

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, node-modules

I am using a [npm library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-material-treetable) `ng-material-treetable`. I want to implement `matsort` and `mat paginator` in this library.

I was trying to add `@ViewChild` method in the ng-material-treetable.js file in fesm5 folder of this library but getting error as `unexpected identifier @`.

Below is the piece of code that was trying to modify (My Line is the piece of code that I have added)-

```
Line 394 to 416
    TreetableComponent.prototype.ngOnInit = /**
         * @return {?}
         */
        @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;                 //My line
        @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;  //My line
        function () {
            var _this = this;
            this.tree = Array.isArray(this.tree) ? this.tree : [this.tree];
            this.options = this.parseOptions(defaultOptions);
            /** @type {?} */
            var customOrderValidator = this.validatorService.validateCustomOrder(this.tree[0], this.options.customColumnOrder);
            if (this.options.customColumnOrder && !customOrderValidator.valid) {
                throw new Error("\n        Properties " + customOrderValidator.xor.map(function (x) { return "'" + x + "'"; }).join(', ') + " incorrect or missing in customColumnOrder");
            }
            this.displayedColumns = this.options.customColumnOrder
                ? this.options.customColumnOrder
                : this.extractNodeProps(this.tree[0]);
            this.searchableTree = this.tree.map(function (t) { return _this.converterService.toSearchableTree(t); });
            /** @type {?} */
            var treeTableTree = this.searchableTree.map(function (st) { return _this.converterService.toTreeTableTree(st); });
            this.treeTable = flatMap(treeTableTree, this.treeService.flatten);
            this.dataSource = this.generateDataSource();
            this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;  //My line
            this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;            //My line
        };
```

Line 497 to 504 -

```
TreetableComponent.decorators = [
        { type: Component, args: [{
                    selector: 'ng-treetable, treetable',
                    // 'ng-treetable' is currently being deprecated
                    template: "<table mat-table [dataSource]=\"dataSource\" matSort [ngClass]=\"formatElevation()\">\n\n  <div *ngFor=\"let column of displayedColumns; first as isFirst;\">\n    <ng-container matColumnDef=\"{{column}}\">\n      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header [ngClass]=\"{'vertical-separator': options.verticalSeparator}\">\n        {{options.capitalisedHeader ? (column | titlecase) : column}}\n      </th>\n      <td mat-cell *matCellDef=\"let element\" [ngClass]=\"{'vertical-separator': options.verticalSeparator}\">\n        <div *ngIf=\"isFirst\">\n          <div class=\"value-cell\">\n            <div [innerHTML]=\"formatIndentation(element)\"></div>\n            <mat-icon [ngStyle]=\"{'visibility': element.children.length ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}\" (click)=\"onNodeClick(element)\">\n              {{element.isExpanded ? 'keyboard_arrow_down' : 'keyboard_arrow_right'}}\n            </mat-icon>\n            <div>{{element.value[column]}}</div>\n          </div>\n        </div>\n        <div *ngIf=\"!isFirst\">\n          {{element.value[column]}}\n        </div>\n      </td>\n    </ng-container>\n  </div>\n\n  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef=\"displayedColumns\"></tr>\n  <tr mat-row [ngClass]=\"{'highlight-on-hover': options.highlightRowOnHover}\" *matRowDef=\"let row; columns: displayedColumns;\"></tr>\n\n</table>\n",
                    styles: ["table{width:100%}.value-cell{display:flex;align-items:center}mat-icon{cursor:pointer}.highlight-on-hover:hover{background-color:#f0f0f5}td[class*=' mat-column']{width:10vw;min-width:10vw;max-width:10vw}.mat-cell,.mat-header-cell{padding:10px}.vertical-separator{border-left:1px solid #f0f0f5}"]
                }] }
    ];
```

Here in this template code I have added `matSort` with table. But this is not working out.Please help if anybody having idea about it.

Note - This piece of code is from that library under folder structure - `ng-material-treetable/fesm5/ng-material-treetable.js`
Thanks in Advance !!

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify the code like this:

```
  TreetableComponent.prototype.ngOnInit =
       sorter?: MatSort;
       @ViewChild(MatSort)
       set sort(ms: MatSort) {
           this.sorter = ms;
           if (this.sorter && this.dataSource) {
              this.dataSource.sort = this.sorter;
           }
       }
       paginator?: MatPaginator;
       @ViewChild(MatPaginator)
       set matPaginator(mp: MatPaginator) {
           this.paginator = mp;
           if (this.paginator && this.dataSource) {
               this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
           }
       }

      function () {
          var _this = this;
          this.tree = Array.isArray(this.tree) ? this.tree : [this.tree];
          this.options = this.parseOptions(defaultOptions);
          /** @type {?} */
          var customOrderValidator = this.validatorService.validateCustomOrder(this.tree[0], this.options.customColumnOrder);
          if (this.options.customColumnOrder && !customOrderValidator.valid) {
              throw new Error("\n        Properties " + customOrderValidator.xor.map(function (x) { return "'" + x + "'"; }).join(', ') + " incorrect or missing in customColumnOrder");
          }
          this.displayedColumns = this.options.customColumnOrder
              ? this.options.customColumnOrder
              : this.extractNodeProps(this.tree[0]);
          this.searchableTree = this.tree.map(function (t) { return _this.converterService.toSearchableTree(t); });
          /** @type {?} */
          var treeTableTree = this.searchableTree.map(function (st) { return _this.converterService.toTreeTableTree(st); });
          this.treeTable = flatMap(treeTableTree, this.treeService.flatten);
          this.dataSource = this.generateDataSource();
      };
```

This may solve your problem because during construction and ngOnInit the paginator/sort can be not ready. In this way as soon as template recognize a paginator/sort it assign it to datasource

Answer (score 0):

This is terrible practice.

When using a NPM library, you're not supposed to edit the code of the said library, and I'll explain why :

When you run `npm i`, you actually install packages from a remote server. THanks to NPM, you don't replace the already existing files **if the version hasn't been modified**.

So it means that you must have a fixed version in your package.json file. Any semver modificator will erase your modification the second you run `npm i`.

But the main issue isn't there : the main issue is with the continuous integration, or the teamwork.

When you push your code to github, **you don't push your node modules**. This means that you don't push your modifications ! And when you have CI, that's your tool that is dowloading the packages, not you : it will download pristine packages, without your modifications.

In the end, the only place where your modification works, is on your own computer.

Finally, even if those issues weren't existing, **the packages are written in Javascript**. Angular is using Typescript : it then compiles the Typescript into a Javascript bundle.

This means that **you can not use Angular code in a JS file**. This means no decorators, no dependency injection. If you want to do that, you will have to find the compiled code for the decorators and the compiled code for the dependency injection.